# unable to loop through a Counter in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, loops, swift

I guys I have a working countdown timer which I can set manually and countdown from this value.

What I'm trying to achieve now though is set my INTERVALS counter to say 3 and loop through the countdown timer the amount of times that I set in this counter then when the last interval is complete the timer finishes

sounds straight forward in my head I know I need a loop somewhere but everything I have tried just hast worked this is my current code before adding a loop. Have tried adding a while statement instead of the if statement but that didn't do the job

I've now added this loop but still no joy. Anyone know how to do this?

```
func runIntervalTimer() {

timerForIntervals = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, 
selector: Selector("updateTimeInterval"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


func updateTimeInterval() {

do {

if intervalCountdown > 0 {
    intervalHasBeenSet = true
    intervalCountdown--
    IntervalTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", intervalCountdown/60, 
    intervalCountdown%60) }
} while intervalHasBeenSet == true

    intervalHasBeenSet = false
    intervalCountdown = 0
    IntervalTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", intervalCountdown/60, 
    intervalCountdown%60)



 }

@IBAction func InterValTimerIncrease(sender: AnyObject) {

 intervalCountdown++
 IntervalTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", intervalCountdown/60, 
 intervalCountdown%60)


 }



 @IBAction func IntervalTimerDecrease(sender: AnyObject) {

 intervalCountdown--
 IntervalTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", intervalCountdown/60,  
 intervalCountdown%60)
  }


@IBAction func IntervalStart(sender: AnyObject) {



    runIntervalTimer()



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably in an infinite loop here:

```
  do {
      if intervalCountdown > 0 {
         intervalHasBeenSet = true
         intervalCountdown--
         IntervalTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", intervalCountdown/60, 
         intervalCountdown%60) }
  } while intervalHasBeenSet == true
```

Your condition is `intervalHasBeenSet == true` but it's never being set to false inside the loop, so it can never exit.

If you want the timer to count down each interval, I think all you need to do is:

```
  func updateTimeInterval() {
       println(intervalCountdown)
       if intervalCountdown > 0 {
         intervalCountdown--
         IntervalTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", intervalCountdown/60, 
         intervalCountdown%60) 
       }
  }
```

Because the `updateTimeInterval` should be called each interval by `NSTimer`, you shouldn't need a loop inside this function.

To have the timer count down multiple times, you need an extra variable (`intervalNum`):

```
  func updateTimeInterval() {
       println(intervalCountdown)
       if intervalCountdown > 0  && intervalNum > 0 {
         // countdown in the current interval
         intervalCountdown--
         IntervalTimer.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", intervalCountdown/60, 
         intervalCountdown%60) 
       }
       else
       {
         // move on to the next interval
         intervalNum--
         intervalCountdown = 20 // or grab the original value from somewhere
       }

       if (intervalNum == 0)
       {   
           // stop the timer
           timerForIntervals.invalidate() 
       }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was actually set to your code before I added the loop and all it did when the counter got to zero was just stop and the interval counter didnt decrease or the timer start again. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I updated my post to include a log statement. What does the value say when you hit the increase and decrease functions?

Comment: What do you actually need to happen when the timer reaches zero?

Comment: no worries I just need the intervals to decrease by 1 then the timer starts again from what ever was set to being with. Then when the intervals are at zero, the counter just stops. Its basically just an interval gym boss. as an example i can set 5 intervals at 20 seconds, 20 seconds completes we goto 4, 20 seconds completes and we goto 3 ect I know im close just cant seem to get it right

Comment: great stuff thanks im due back shortly will give that a go and let you know how it goes :-)

Comment: thanks this works, do you know where you say interval countdown = 20 or some other number, how would I set this to what ever it was set to previously? so say i set intervals to 4, counter 20, it counts down, intervals decrease....how would i get the next interval to go from 20 (or what ever was set previously) hope this makes sense.  thanks

Comment: how would I grab the original value, every works once I can grab the original value i ll be rocking...cheers

Comment: sorted it created a local variable to store the increased count, then passed it in!!!

Comment: Great! I would've suggested the same thing.